# Go Interface method returning a pointer to itself

Tags: go

I am working with an upstream package in Go that provide a typical that has methods returning pointers to the same structure (like a typical builder pattern). For example:

```
type Dog struct {
    AddCollar() *Dog
}
```

For some reasons, I would like to mock this structure in certain scenarios (such as for local development, or when some `Dog` properties do not exist etc...).

I decided to make a generic interface:

```golang
type Animal interface {
    AddCollar() Animal
}
```

My first instinct was to return `Animal` here, not `*Animal`, as a pointer to an interface don't seem to make sense (and did not seem to work either).

And my mock being simply this, that really does nothing (in comparison, upstream `Dog` would do much more work that are not needed in that case):

```golang
type DogMock struct{}
func (d *DogMock) AddCollar() *DogMock {return d}
```

However, after writing down and trying to use my mock structure, I am getting:

```
need method: AddCollar() Animal
have method: AddCollar() *DogMock
```

But my `*DogMock` object actually implements `Animal`.
Both signatures are returning the same error:

```
type DogMock struct{}
func (d *DogMock) AddCollar() *DogMock {return d}
func (d *DogMock) AddCollar() Animal {return d}
```

Note that `func (d *DogMock) AddCollar() Animal {return d}` does not seem to be the solution because I am not able to edit the upstream structure `Dog`, with method `AddCollar()` which returns `*Dog`, not `Animal`.

Is there a way to specify in my `Animal` interface to return a pointer to its own structure?

Comment: No, there is not. `*DogMock` will only implement `Animal` if `Animal.AddCollar()`  has return type `*DogMock`. Also there's a typo in your `type Animal struct{ ... }` typedef, it should be `type Animal interface{ ... }`.

Comment: Your `type Dog` is not an interface (but a struct) and thus cannot be "mocked" at all. If it would be an interface type you could provide a "mock" implementation but Go's type system provides no contravariance, so the ApplyCollar method _always_ _must_ return a *Dog. Also note that your `type Animal` is again a struct and not an interface so your question "Is there a way to specify in my Animal interface to return a pointer to its own structure?" makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: type Animal interface {
    AddCollar() Animal
}

type DogMock struct{
}
func (d *DogMock) AddCollar() Animal {return d}

func doSmth(a Animal) {
 fmt.Println(a.AddCollar())
}
func main() {
 doSmth(new(DogMock))
}

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers and pointing me out the typo on Animal, it is indeed an interface. So it seems that there is no way to mock a struct like what I am trying to achieve, I'll need to fix that problem in a different way then. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your DogMock just needs to return Animal. Once DogMock returns Animal then it is an Animal and you can return *DogMock as Animal.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Animal interface {
    AddCollar() Animal
    AddLeash() Animal
}

type Dog struct {
    HasCollar bool
    HasLeash  bool
}

func (d *Dog) AddCollar() Animal {
    d.HasCollar = true
    return d
}

func (d *Dog) AddLeash() Animal {
    d.HasLeash = true
    return d
}

func main() {
    var a Animal = &Dog{}

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", a)
    a.AddCollar().AddLeash()
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", a)
}
```